# Why a formula must be closed in order to prove decidability?

Tags: logic

Based on this from https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Decidable_formula

> A decidable formula is a formula A of a given formal system that is either provable in this system (that is, is a theorem) or refutable (that is, its negation ¬A is provable). If every closed formula of a given formal system is decidable, then such a system is said to be complete.

I'm wondering, why decidability is required for only the closed formulas (sentences)?

Second, my question arrises from Presburguer Arithmetic study. One of our goals is to **compute truth value** of presburguer formulas. For this, we proceed by first eliminating quantifiers (i.e., generating a logicaly equivalente closed formula).

Thanks in advance,

Pedro

Comment: I am *fairly* certain that decision theory is the theory behind making decisions, and not behind decidability of formulas.

Comment: A formula with free variables cannot be a theorem.  From the article you linked: "Note that it is impossible to require that all, and not just the closed, formulas be decidable in the system. Thus, the formula $x=0$, where $x$ runs over natural numbers, expresses neither a true nor a false proposition and therefore neither it nor its negation is a theorem of formal arithmetic."

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I believe so, was a mistake fulfilling the tags.

Comment: @DanBrumleve: yes, I read that line, but it isnt clear enought to me.

Comment: @DanBrumleve: I believe that often "$x=x$" is included as a logical axiom in first-order logic (with equality).  (Note that this is not closed.)

Comment: @Arthur: I always thought this was quantified, $\forall x.x=x$.

Comment: @Asaf: Shoenfield's text just has the open formula.  Mendelson does not appear to use any axiom of $=$ in the logic itself (though his examples of theories do list the sentence forms), but he does have as logical axioms formulae of the form "$( \forall x ) ( \varphi (x) ) \rightarrow \varphi (t)$" where $t$ is a term substitutible for $x$ in $\varphi$, which are in general not closed.

Comment: (The last line of my previous comment should have read, "_... which are not in general closed._"; damned non-commmutativity of English!)  The point being that every deductive system for first-order logic that I have encountered includes ways of proving theorems which are not sentences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea comes from the definition of satisfaction of arbitrary formulae with a model $\mathcal{A}$.  Suppose that $\varphi ( x_1 , \ldots , x_n )$ is a formula (with all free variables shown).  We say that $\mathcal{A} \models \varphi ( x_1 , \ldots , x_n )$ iff $\mathcal{A} \models \varphi [ a_1 , \ldots , a_n ]$ for all choices of $a_1 , \ldots , a_n \in A$.  The notation $\varphi [a_1 , \ldots , a_n]$ indicates that we are "replacing" the free occurrences of these variables with the indicated elements of the universe.  We then ask whether the resulting "statement" is true in $\mathcal{A}$ about these elements.

It then follows quite easily that such formulae need not be either true or false in a given model.

> Consider something nice and simple like the theory of the (additive) group $\mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z}$ under the language $\{ + , 0 \}$.  This is clearly a complete theory, since it has (up to isomorphism) a unique (finite) model.
>
> A perfectly good non-closed formula is $x + x = 0$.
>
> * Is this formula true in $\mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z}$?  Certainly not since $\mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z} \models  2 + 2 = 4 \neq 0$.
>   * Is its negation true in $\mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z}$?  Again no, since $\mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z} \models 3 + 3 = 0$.

Since open formulae may fail to be either true or false in models, these formulae may also fail to be either formal theorems or negations of formal theorems.  Since virtually all interesting theories have such formulae, it makes sense to only speak of sentences (closed formulae) when discussing decidability.  (Otherwise models of decidable theories would have the property that their elements all satisfy the same formulae, which, as the above example indicates,  is a very strong condition.)

Comment: thanks very much, really good answer.